# Java Internatiolization

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization

I am planning to make a website written in JSP/Java available in multiple languages, now I wonder how I would do that in a nice manner, currently I got one proposal as approach, but I also wonder if something else is possible.

The proposal: Have a class Language.java responsible for managing the language, preferably the data itself should be stored in for example .txt files, atleast some simple format that others (possibly non-programming related) can also work with.

Very basic setup:

english.lang:

```
RegisterUsername => Username
RegisterPassword => Password
RegisterPasswordConfirmed => Confirm password
```

Calling code:

```
Language language = new Language(); 
//constructor of Language should determine what language to use
System.out.println(Language.get("RegisterUsername"));
//would show the string in the respective language
```

Second thought: Some code like `${RegisterUserName}` would even be more handy, but I'm afraid that this is not possible.

How should I implement the internatiolization?

Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC, somehow though the question is not a duplicate (in my opinion), but that answer is definately one I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry I have been to quick, I am unable to use what you have suggested in the other thread in pure Java, how would I do so?

Comment: Just use `java.util.ResourceBundle` API, as JSTL is also using under covers. Note: it's absolutely not recommended to write down Java code in JSP. I assume that you actually mean a servlet class when you said "pure Java".

Comment: Indeed I meant a server class, and I'll take a look at the ResourceBundles then.